# How to level sloped concrete

Tags: concrete, leveling

I am using concrete bricks for an outdoor fireplace base.  The concrete slopes downhill.  Can I use cement patch to raise it 1/2" over  5' x 30 " span?

Comment: Will the concrete bricks sit on a concrete slab that slopes downhill? Will they sit directly on dirt? Do you need to raise it 1/2" over a 5' span or over a 30" span? Please [edit] your question to clarify these details.

Comment: How long would you like it to look good for, 1/2/5/10/25 years?  If 1 or 2 years yes.  Anything else it is easier (cheaper if your time has value) to pour a thicker slab than do the prep work required to make concrete patch stable in a 1/2" lift over a decent period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

Use diamond saw and cut the concrete block in an angle, so they sit straight.

Solution 2:

Build a concrete platform to level the bricks.

A cement patch 1/2 inch thick over 5 foot long sitting on a plain dirt/ground wont last a day.